# PyQt5 - how to bind a signal to an object type rather than an object instance?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am able to bind slots and signals for simple examples.  However, I would like to bind a signal to any instance of an object - say any QPushButton - and let the slot determine which object is the sender.

Here is my simple [example](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/eventssignals/) of binding to explicit QPushButton instances:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton, QApplication 

class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        btn1 = QPushButton("Button 1", self)
        btn1.move(30, 50)

        btn2 = QPushButton("Button 2", self)
        btn2.move(150, 50)

        btn3 = QPushButton("Button 3", self)
        btn3.move(30, 150)

        btn4 = QPushButton("Button 4", self)
        btn4.move(150, 150)

        # This code ties the slots and signals together
        # clicked is the SIGNAL
        btn1.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)
        btn2.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)
        btn3.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)
        btn4.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

        self.statusBar()

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 230)
        self.setWindowTitle('Event sender')
        self.show()


    def buttonClicked(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        self.statusBar().showMessage(sender.text() + ' was pressed firmly')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The code is not PEP8 compliant but is used for example purposes only.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if I understood you correctly, but try the example below:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton, QApplication 

class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        self.data = data
        self.statusBar()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        for b in self.data:
            btn = QPushButton(b[0], self)    
            btn.move(b[1], b[2])
            btn.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

    def buttonClicked(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        self.statusBar().showMessage(sender.text() + ' was pressed firmly')

data = [["Button 1",  30,  50],
        ["Button 2", 150,  50],
        ["Button 3",  30, 150],
        ["Button 4", 150, 150] ]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example(data)
    ex.show()
    ex.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 230)
    ex.setWindowTitle('Event sender')    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: @s-nick  That is a great programmatic approach (and much better Python than mine!).  It still explicitly binds each instance of QPushButton in the for loop.   My goal is to bind the buttonClicked() function to any instance of QPushButton which is clicked.

Comment: Any section in particular?  That is a large section and it is designed for the C++ library rather than Python - which has some variation over the original spec.

Comment: Still hoping for a Pythonic method of doing this.